# Pyramid won't find includeme-function of submodule

Tags: python, pyramid

I want to outsource route configuration properly into the corresponding module. For that pyramid-docs specify that I can define:

```
def includeme(config):
    config.add_route('foo_list', '/foo', factory='.api.foo.models.example_factory')
```

My Folder structure is the following:

```
    /projectname/api/foo
```

in the example folder, there are the files:

```
__init__.py (with includeme()-function)
views.py
models.py
```

Now I need to include this "foo"-module on application initialization.
this is why I defined:

File:

```
    /projectname/__init__.py
```

Code:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    config.include('.api.foo')
```

But when I try to run the application, pyramid throws the following exception:

```
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projectname.api.foo.api'
```

(That was copied and pasted - it searches for /api/foo/api - which is incorrect)

Are there any factors for configuration that I don't take into account?
I tried the following:

```
Changing the /projectname/__init__.py code into:
```

```
    config.include('.api.foo.includeme')
```

which results in the same error.

If I rename the function from includeme to anything else, it says

```
    pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationError: module 'projectname.api.foo' has no attribute 'includeme'
```

any advice?

Comment: Why did you use leading dots in your `include()` and `factory` parameters?

Comment: To access the right folder, but I actually fixed the problem - when I tried to include with "config.include('.api.foo')" and it jumped into includeme()-Function, the path to the route_factory was wrong - the line had to be "config.add_route('foo_list', '/foo', factory='.models.example_factory')", since the function was already in the correct folder.